JSDOC: Private name is not defined
I am trying to document some classes using JSdoc comments and the JSdoc plugin.
/**
 * @category SomeCategory
 * @class
 * @extends someClass
 * @description Lorem ipsum
 */
class ExampleClass extends someClass{
    #data: string[];

    /**
   * Constructs the ExampleClass.*/
    constructor() {
        this.#data = [];
    }

    public addData(newData: string): void {
        this.#data.push(newData);
        this.#logData(newData);
    }

    public getData(): string[] {
        return this.#data.slice();
    }

    /**
     * Processes the data by converting all entries to uppercase.
     * @private
     */
    #processData(): void {
        this.#data = this.#data.map(d => d.toUpperCase());
    }

    public triggerDataProcessing(): void {
        this.#processData();
    }
}


However when I run the script to generate the html documentation I get this error:
ERROR: Unable to parse: Private name #processData is not defined.
